# What does "possibly due to conflict resolution" mean in the empty cherry-pick message?

Tags: git

When you try to cherry-pick a commit that is already in the current branch, the message

```
The previous cherry-pick is now empty, possibly due to conflict resolution.
```

will be shown.

The meaning of that is clear.

However, the message clearly covers some other situation and I don't understand the other case - *possibly due to conflict resolution.*
How can a conflict resolution make a commit empty?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git cherry-pick not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072013/git-cherry-pick-not-working)

Comment: I agree it is similar, but my question is quite general and it's not about cherry-pick per se. I want to understand, basically, how can a commit disappear in a process of resolving conflicts as the hint implies - possibly due to conflict resolution.

Comment: You might want to reword the question, then, especially the subject line. E.g., perhaps something like: "how would conflict resolution make a commit empty, so that you need to use `--skip` during a Git `rebase` or `am`?"

Answer (score 15):

When you cherry pick a commit, git tries to apply a patch. Three outcomes are possible:

- no change, because the patch was already in ancestors (e.g. when you try to cherry-pick twice)
- some changes applied
- conflicts in files

If there are conflicts in files, you can edit them, called "conflict resolution". One way of editing them is to remove all the changes that the cherry-pick would have added. When you do so, you end up with no more changes anywhere, but still the cherry-pick being in progress. That's why this hint says "possibly due to conflict resolution".