# Empty Cherry Picks on Git Rebase

Tags: git

I've never seen this before, and I have no idea what's happening. I'm trying to rebase commits on a branch interactively.

```
git rebase -i

pick caa159b feat: user page
pick 3ca1c9d feat: profile page
pick 26230ec fix: user page fix

==>

pick caa159b feat: user page
squash 3ca1c9d fix: user page fix
pick 26230ec feat: profile page
```

But when I run it, I'm getting this error which I've never seen before.

```
The previous cherry-pick is now empty, possibly due to conflict resolution.
If you wish to commit it anyway, use:

    git commit --allow-empty

Otherwise, please use 'git cherry-pick --skip'
interactive rebase in progress; onto dc2c1aa
Last command done (1 command done):
   pick caa159b feat: user page
Next commands to do (2 remaining commands):
   squash 26230ec fix: user page
   pick 3ca1c9d feat: profile page
You are currently rebasing branch 'staging' on 'dc2c1aa'.
```

Can someone explain what's going on here? There is no conflict from what I can tell.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "possibly due to conflict resolution" mean in the empty cherry-pick message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42139028/what-does-possibly-due-to-conflict-resolution-mean-in-the-empty-cherry-pick-me)

Comment: Is this repeatable? If you abort and try again does it happen again?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt No that doesn't answer my question. None of those cases apply. @TTT This happens every time. `git reset HEAD~` then `git rebase -i`. I make those changes, then I see that error.

Comment: @fny I asked because the bottom output has the squash and pick IDs swapped, which looks like maybe you had them out of order somehow.

Comment: What is the purpose of this command: `git reset HEAD~` before the interactive rebase?

Comment: Sorry, I undo the last mega commit recommit smaller commits, and then rebase to clean up. Interestingly, everything appears to work from Sourcetree but not the command line.

Comment: What do those two commits that you're squashing together do? Can you provide a [mcve]? What is the difference between the current base and the new base? There are many ways you can end up with an empty commit and they are not generally errors.