# Conflict cherry-picking a commit range but not when picking each individually?

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

I have a `develop` and a `release` branch.

I created a patch branch from `develop` with 6 commits A, B, C, D, E, F (with `A` being the oldest). It was reviewed and then three-way merged back into `develop`.

I then created a similar fix branch from `release` (for review) and cherry picked commits from my `develop`-based fix branch onto my `release`-based fix branch like so:

```
git checkout release/patch/ticket1

git cherry-pick A^..F
```

This resulted in an unexpected merge conflict while applying patches.

I `git cherry-pick --abort`ed and instead tried

```
git cherry-pick A
git cherry-pick B
git cherry-pick C
git cherry-pick D
git cherry-pick E
git cherry-pick F
```

And this worked without conflict.

I thought `cherry-pick` created a patch from each commit and applied them in sequence to the target branch?

So how is it possible that I have encountered a merge conflict when specifying a *range* but not when applying *individual* commits?

Related

- [git cherry-pick not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072013/git-cherry-pick-not-working/7072029#7072029)
- [What does cherry-picking a commit with git mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339429/what-does-cherry-picking-a-commit-with-git-mean)

EDIT

I attempted tests suggested from the comments and could not reproduce my problem. As my understanding of the cherry-pick sequencer is correct, I'll have to assume the intervention of some other actor (IDE, locking watcher process?).

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Is it possible for you to create a minimal example?

Comment: At which commit the conflict happens? What happens you you apply first only `A`, then `B^..F`, and other combinations like this? If first commits in series applied succesfully, are the results same?

Comment: Your description matches how the cherry-pick sequencer works, so as long as `A^..F` selects those six commits in that order, this should work. Try `git rev-list --reverse --topo-order A^..F` to see if you get those six commits in that order (we need the `--reverse --topo-order` here since the default order is commit date based).

Comment: @jsageryd I'm loathe to post any question without a [mcve] but sadly my code is closed-source (or I would have just linked the repo). Thank you max360 and torek, I'll take a look shortly and update the question.

Comment: torek, max360: I attempted both, and tried selecting smaller ranges, and could not reproduce my problem. As my understanding of the cherry-pick sequencer was correct, I'll have to assume the intervention of some other actor (IDE, some watcher process?) mucking about. *Please join me in closing this question.* Thank you all for your input.