# Cherry-pick merge commit failing with empty commit

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

I have a couple of branches, and I want the changes from the second branch to appear in the first branch.

It's probably best described with a diagram:

```
          X - Y - Z    (branch-2)
         /         \
A - B - C - D - E - F  (master)
 \     
  G - H - I            (branch-1)
```

I want to merge `X`, `Y`, `Z` into `branch-1` without bringing `B` and `C`.

I tried to cherry-pick merge-commit `F`, and although I specify the correct parent (I think), the cherry-pick fails with: `The previous cherry-pick is now empty, possibly due to conflict resolution.`

Should I cherry-pick the `X^..Z` range? Or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Yes I think you're right. You can cherry-pick the three `X`, `Y` and `Z` commits in the right order, and then you can optionally reduce those 3 commits into a single one with a `git rebase -i <sha1-of-I>~1` command.

Comment: I would cherry-pick one by one. Also have a look at this [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072013/git-cherry-pick-not-working) to understand your error message.

Comment: The graph drawing doesn't show which parent is which, but probably you would need `-m 2` rather than the more typical `-m 1`. Your proposed solution (pick `X^..Z`) is probably the best way anyway though. Note that you can use `-n` to combine them in the index as you go, and make one commit at the end, although I'd probably do the interactive rebase squash as well since that means I get to resolve any conflicts as I go, and make sure I did not break anything before squashing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cherrypicking one by one might be a solution if that `branch-2` is small.

For larger branches to move I'd do this:

```
git checkout branch-2
git branch   moving/branch-2 # new branch to work with
git rebase --onto  branch-1 [sha_of_c] moving/branch-2 # move commits of branch ontop of the other 
git checkout branch-1 
git reset --hard  moving/branch-2 # set branch lable to new HEAD
git branch -d  moving/branch-2 # clean up
```

As suggested by **@quetzalcoatl** in the comments you might use the `-i` swithch with `rebase` so you can check that the right commits are being copied before actually doing that.

On the other Hand if something went wrong you can simply revert `moving/branch-2` to `branch-2` and start over again.

Comment: just one note - for all people "not feeling safe with rebase", add `-i` to `rebase`. This will display you a list of commits that will be taken, and you can edit (i.e. remove, reorder, etc) the plan beforewards. This is super-handy. I actually rarely use rebase without -i, because I tend to mistake the order of branches for --onto/etc parameters and it's better to check the plan first.