# changes from last commit are not included in the working branch

Tags: git

I was worked on branch A, on Test1: I did some changes and commit them/

Then I switch branches to the branch B, work on a few other tickets, and then go back to branch A.

But now my ticket `Test1` does not include changes from the commit.
In the Git history, I can see the changes, but they are not in my local, so I have got a lot of error.

I tried to cherry pick, and receive this:

```
0f763739 Test1 - last changes The previous cherry-pick is now empty, 
                 possibly due to conflict resolution. 
If you wish to commit it anyway, use:  git commit --allow-empty  
Otherwise, please use 'git reset'
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You should not need to cherry-pick Test1 last commit, especially if you are in Test1 branch, at that very commit.

Such a [cherry-pick would be a no-op](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7072029/6309), hence your error message.

If you don't see your files:

1. Double-check git status to confirm you are on Test1 branch
2. Do a `git restore -- .`